# Group theory Definition normalizes

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and consider $x\in G$ and $H\leq G$. What does it mean? "$x$ normalizes $H$".
Let $A\subseteq G$. What does it mean? "$A$ inverts $x$".

Comment: Where did you see that thing "A inverts x" ??

Comment: On edge-transitive Cayley graphs of valency four

Comment: Beats me, @hamed: never heard of that. Perhaps someone else...

Comment: A Paper. It has been written that there are $q-1$ involutions $\tau _i$ of $G$ which inverts $x$. $x\in G$.

Comment: Wild guessing: $A$ inverts $x$ might mean that $a^{-1}xa=x^{-1}$ for all $a\in A$??

Comment: Ok thanks a lot  DonAntonio

Comment: Dear Hagon, I think you are right. because it is possible for the sentence which I read.

Answer (score 4):

By definition

$$x\;\;\text{normalizes}\;\;H\iff H^x:=x^{-1}Hx=H\iff$$

$$\iff\;\forall\,h\in H\;\;\exists\,h'\in H\;\;s.t.\;\; x^{-1}hx=h'$$