# Definition of "one element normalizes another element"

Tags: group-theory, definition

I understand that someone has asked [the definition of 
"an element of a group normalizes a subgroup"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/619670/group-theory-definition-normalizes). Let $G$ be a group and $a,b\in G$. Then what does "$a$ normalizes $b$" mean? Does it make sense at all, or does it just mean that $a$ commutes with $b$?

I came across this when I was reading the [wikipedia article on Holomorph (mathematics).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorph_(mathematics))
There is one section as follows:[image]

It says that "Such an $f$ normalizes any $\lambda(g)$, and the only $\lambda(g)$ that fixes the identity is $\lambda(1)$."

Here $g\in G$ and $\lambda:G\to \mathrm{Sym}(G)$; thus both $f$ and $\lambda(g)$ are elements (instead of subgroups) of $\mathrm{Sym}(G)$. Then what does "$f$ normalizes $\lambda(g)$" mean?

Comment: Yes, commutes would be appropriate - if $a$ and $b$ commute, then $a$ normalizes, and even centralizes $\langle b \rangle$.

Comment: @NickyHekster, thanks for the comment. As in the quoted section from wikipedia, I do not see why $f$ commutes with $\lambda(g)$.

Comment: Yes, this is not the right formulation on the Wiki page - it should be $f$ normalizes $\lambda[G]$, so the image of $G$ in $\text{Sym}(G)$.

Comment: @NickyHekster, thanks! Now everything is clear; I have made an edit to correct the mistake on Wikipedia as well.